# Simple change of App Theme

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, themes

I'm trying to change the App Theme into `Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` (Classic Light).

AndroidManifest.xml: (I was told to add a Blank Activity first and add the Login Activity, then swapping the names `Login` and `Main`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.administrator.helloworld" >
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
</application>
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

activity_login.xml: (Login Activity template that I used and modified.)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.administrator.helloworld.LoginActivity"
>

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="470dp"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/syncz"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Login:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml: (Haven't been configured, it's going to be the menu later on.)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml: (No changes)

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Photo of general frontpage design - [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71afT.jpg)

---

Final Edit - It turns out that the way to do it was the same command that I had used earlier but back then I got errors while running it. I must have changed something without knowing it, I don't know but the good news are that it's fixed and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this code in application tag of androidmanifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can also refer [Create Project](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html) to start from the beginning. After understanding that you can refer [Training Lessons](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

To make it simple, check this in mainfest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

check this in styles.xml:

```
parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Tried that before comming here :) It gives me an error. :/

Comment: Give me the name of the file that you want me to check and I'll post it immediately! :)

Comment: It's added to the post now. Currently trying to make my emulator work... Sorry

Comment: Error is in the androidmanifest file : try to add this line in application tag :- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
(In your code it is   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ,so change that)

check this in styles.xml:-parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: Well what do you know.... It actually worked for some reason. I swear to you that I tried exactly that command earlier this day! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen with activities not with application theme, to customize app theme use [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and for those activities you don't want the title bar apply it in activity tag not in application tag

1) download zip file

2) import the res files into res folders

and then in you manifest apply the theme like this in application tag :

```
<application
 ....
 android:theme="@style/Theme.app theme" 
 .....
```

if you want to open the app with the activity with no title bar do this

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme=“@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen” 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: My idea of opening the app is that is opens a page with no action bars or anything, just a logo at the top/middleish and login fields below :) I can't seem to find that with your useful tool :(

Comment: add  Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen to launcher activity

Comment: got it? if you don't then let me know

Comment: I'll know in 10-20 mins time, it's rough working on 2 gb RAM :)

Android Studio + Emulator takes up 93% of my memory :D

Comment: Alright, so I've tried your method but can't seem to make it work. I'll post some of my files in the post now :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so as it seems, you are a beginner and beginners always concern too much about the appearance of the theme as I used to do.  Simply follow these steps: 
1) Decide what kind of app you want to make (dont bother about UI)
2) Instead of watching every video of whatever tutorial you have choosen, only go through those videos that are helpful for your project. I know poeple are keen to watch everything that they find interesting. but control your emotions and go for whats useful :p.
3) At some stage, you will realize that u know enough of what you should know at that stage
4) You will automatically come across situations where you will be able to create your own theme using .

PS - from my expericience :p

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely take this into consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to change the theme into Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen you need to include the below in androidmanifest.xml file

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoTilteBar.Fullscreen"
   android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```

You can add more theme in Styles.xml file .For this click res folder->values->styles

sample code to  get an idea:

styles.xml :-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

Androidmanifest.xml :-

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

So here you can see this line < android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > in androidmanifest file

"@style" this means the style xml file in res folder 
So In  style.xml file you add more theme as your choice

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can go into styles.xml add another <style next to the one I have and use reference name in "@style/name" ? :)

Comment: In my opinion as a beginner this a good site to start(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).It helped a lot to a basic idea.....                                  A theme is a style applied to an entire Activity or application, rather than an individual View (as in the example above). When a style is applied as a theme, every View in the Activity or application will apply each style property that it supports. For example, you can apply the same CodeFont style as a theme for an Activity and then all text inside that Activity will have green monospace font.